# Kotlin exposed - Entity for table with no identity column

Tags: sql, postgresql, kotlin, primary-key, kotlin-exposed

All of the material I can find on Kotlin exposed library assumes that the table has a primary identity column, and so the entities are in most examples shown inherit the `IntEntity` abstract class. For Example:

```
class UserLocation(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<UserLocation>(UserLocations)

    var userId by UserLocations.userId
    var user by User referencedOn UserLocations.user
    var recordedAt by UserLocations.recordedAt
    var insertedAt by UserLocations.insertedAt
    var point by UserLocations.point
```

And that corresponds to this table definition:

```
object UserLocations : IntIdTable("user_locations") {

    val userId = integer("user_id")
    val user = reference("user_id", Users)
    val recordedAt = datetime("recorded_at").nullable()
    val insertedAt = datetime("inserted_at")
    val point = point("point")
}
```

The problem is, my table actually doesn't have an identity column. I know all the negative ramifications of a table not having a primary key, but unfortunately I only have read access to this table. I cannot get write access to this table to add a primary key.

At one point in the wiki of the exposed library it mentions that the object table definition can inherit `Table` instead of `IntIdTable`, however that would require that the entity inherit something different and I can't quite find what the entity should inherit instead of `IntEntity`.

My Question: **What should my entity inherit (instead of `IntEntity`) when the table has no id column.**

Comment: Could you show your current table definition which you want to use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exposed DAO requires some identity to fetch and store entities from a table. It doesn't require to be a primary or auto-increment column but in that case, you have to ensure that the values in that column are unique.

For example, you may map Entity to a Table with String id:

```
object FooTable : IdTable<String>() {
    val myIdColumn = varchar("my_id_column", 50).uniqueIndex()
    override val id: Column<EntityID<String>> = myIdColumn.entityId()
}

class FooEntity(id: String) : Entity<String>(id) {
    companion object : EntityClass<String, FooEntity>(FooTable)
}
```

Comment: what if i want to use the PrimaryKey as the identifier in Dao entity?

Answer (score 3):

The Kotlin exposed API comes with two parts. It comes with a DAO API and a DSL API. See the [readme](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed) for more details. You need to use the DSL API if you do not have some kind of id table/primary key. The DSL API is much closer to raw SQL, but will still prevent stuff like SQL injection, and be typesafe.

In short, what you want to do can't/shouldn't be done, use the DSL API instead.

Comment: Can you use both Dao objects and Dsl objects in one database with references between the two?